# Issues writing market research data to csv from a txt file with regex

Tags: python, regex

Currently, I am using this algorithm to parse text into a CSV file for market research.

```
import re

def text2csv(inname, outname):
    with open(inname, 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        data = f.read().strip().replace('\n', '\t').replace(',', '')
        print(data)
    print("check1")
    #info = re.findall(r'\t(.*?)\ is\ (.*?\t\t.*?)\t\t.*?Founded Year:\ (.*?)\t\tHeadquarters:\ (.*?)\t\tWebsite:\ (.*?)\t\t.*?\tFounders:\ (.*?)\t', data, re.MULTILINE)

    info = re.findall(r'\t(.*?)\ is\ (.*?\t\t.*?)\t\t.*?Founding Year:\ (.*?)\t\tHeadquarters:\ (.*?)\t\tWebsite:\ (.*?)\t\t.*?\tFounders:\ (.*?)\t', data, re.MULTILINE)
    print(data)
    with open(outname, 'w', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        f.write('Name,Description,Founding Year,Headquarters,Website,Founders\n')

        for i in info:
            f.write(','.join(i).replace('\t', '') + '\n')

text2csv("proptech.txt", "proptech.csv")
```

This algorithm worked for a text structure such as this:

```
Big Hit Entertainment is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

Big Hit Entertainment is a South Korean entertainment company that currently manages soloist Lee Hyun and idol group BTS. It helps bring the music and content from various sources in one place on its innovative platform.

Founded Year: 2005
Headquarters: Seoul, Seoul-t’ukpyolsi, South Korea
Website: www.ibighit.com
Twitter: www.twitter.com/bighitent
Founders: Bang Si-Hyuk

One97 Communications is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

One97 is a startup that delivers mobile content and commerce services to millions of mobile consumers. It does so through India’s most widely deployed telecom applications cloud platform.

Founded Year: 2000
Headquarters: Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India
Website: www.one97.com
LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/one97-communications-limited
Twitter: www.twitter.com/One97
Founders: Vijay Shekhar Sharma
```

But the algorithm seems to fall apart when the structure is changed to this:

```
NestAway is one of the top proptech startups for 2020

This Bangalore-based startup is a home rental network that aims to provide better rental solutions via design and technology. Their motto is to assist customers in booking, finding, and moving into a rental home of choice across Indian cities. All of this is made possible within an application. They also help their customer’s move-in, ask for services from tap leakage to door lock broken, rental payment, etc. Alongside this, they also assist customers in moving out. Here is some more information about this venture, one of the top proptech startups for 2020.

Founding Year: 2015

Headquarters: Bangalore, India

Website: www.nestaway.com

LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/9334060/

Founders: Amarendra Sahu, Deepak Dhar, Jitendra Jagadev, Smruti Parida



Ucommune is one of the top proptech startups for 2020

This startup offers co-working space solutions. They also have provision for long-term leasing, hot desk, and corporate customization and professional solutions. They provide services to small-to-medium enterprises across China, Singapore, New York City, San Francisco in California, and London in the United Kingdom. Here is some more information about this venture, one of the top proptech startups for 2020.

Founding Year: 2015

Headquarters: Beijing, China

Website: www.ucommune.com

LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/ucommune

Founders: Mao Daqing
```

I am very new to using regex, but hoping to get help fixing my code to a) work and b) work more universally. I am currently working on gathering market research data from lists on hexgn.com, and their website is not dynamic so it is tough to simply scrape data from the site using google chrome plugins. Sadly, the structure in which they make their lists isn't always the same, so in this case what is messing me up is that the second line doesn't have the company name and "is" as the first words in the description. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could attempt to do this with regex but a simpler approach would not use it in my opinion, Assuming a company always starts with a description (which itself starts with " is....") and finishes with "Founders:...".

To get the data as a list of dictionaries:

```
FIELDS = [
    "Founding Year:",
    "Headquarters:",
    "Website:",
    "LinkedIn:"
]

def text2csv(inname, outname):
    companies = [{
        "Name": None,
        "Description": "",
        "Founding Year": None,
        "Headquarters": None,
        "Website": None,
        "Founders": None,
        "LinkedIn": None
    }]
    with open(inname, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as input_data:
        for line in input_data:
            if not line.startswith("Founders:"):
                data = line.strip()
                if data:
                    data_field = next((field.replace(":", "") for field in FIELDS if data.startswith(field)), None)
                    if data_field:
                        companies[-1][data_field] = data.split(":", 1)[-1].strip()
                    else:
                        companies[-1]["Description"] += data
                        if companies[-1]["Name"] is None:
                            companies[-1]["Name"] = data.split(" is")[0]

            else:
                companies[-1]["Founders"] = line.strip().split(":", 1)[-1].strip()
                companies.append({
                    "Name": None,
                    "Description": "",
                    "Founding Year": None,
                    "Headquarters": None,
                    "Website": None,
                    "Founders": None
                })
        companies.pop()
        for company in companies:
            print()
            for field, value in company.items():
                print(field, value)
```

Produces:

```
Name NestAway
Description NestAway is one of the top proptech startups for 2020This Bangalore-based startup is a home rental network that aims to provide better rental solutions via design and technology. Their motto is to assist customers in booking, finding, and moving into a rental home of choice across Indian cities. All of this is made possible within an application. They also help their customer’s move-in, ask for services from tap leakage to door lock broken, rental payment, etc. Alongside this, they also assist customers in moving out. Here is some more information about this venture, one of the top proptech startups for 2020.
Founding Year 2015
Headquarters Bangalore, India
Website www.nestaway.com
Founders Amarendra Sahu, Deepak Dhar, Jitendra Jagadev, Smruti Parida
LinkedIn www.linkedin.com/company/9334060/

Name Ucommune
Description Ucommune is one of the ....
Founding Year 2015
Headquarters Beijing, China
Website www.ucommune.com
Founders Mao Daqing
LinkedIn www.linkedin.com/company/ucommune
```

You could then used these dictionaries to print to a csv file quite easily, python has in built modules to help you https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html